# Django: Celery throws an error when I import Django model or function when I am using it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I have a problem with the configuration of Celery with Django.

When I attempt to import function like this into the Celery file:

```
def add_proxy():
    proxy = ProxyList(timezone.now())
    proxy.save()
```

running command:

```
celery -A estatefilter_backend worker -l info
```

causes error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I'm using Python 3.7.5 and Django 2.2.7.

Comment: Did you read the error message and do as directed? `python manage.py ...` will set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` for you, but `celery ...` won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os.environ.setdefault()` line must be before any imports that might import Django modules, e.g.:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'estatefilter_backend.settings')

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from scrapper.add_scrape import add_proxy

app = Celery('estatefilter_backend', broker='amqp://localhost')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```